# Loki: Internal Server Error. 500. table loki_index2711 does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, grafana-loki

The above error is received when adding Loki as a data source for Grafana. Loki is deployed using values.yaml after changing the following sections.

```
schema_config:
configs:
- from: 2021-10-24
  store: cassandra
  object_store: cassandra
  schema: v11
  index:
    prefix: loki_index
    period: 168h
  chunks:
    prefix: chunk
    period: 168h
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
storage_config:
  Cassandra:
    addresses: cassandra.loki.svc.cluster.local:9042                                                                                                                                                                   
    auth: true
    username: Cassandra
    password: Cassandra
    keyspace: loki
chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 168h
```

Promtail is deployed using the following command.

```
helm upgrade promtail1 --namespace=loki grafana/promtail  --set config.lokiAddress=http://loki1.loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
```

Cassandra contains only the loki keyspace (without tables or indexes).

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After switch to grafana/loki:2.3.0, the problem disappeared. And It seems happened in release version 2.4.0 ~ 2.4.1.
Check the start logs I found the `table_manager` module not initialized in the latest version, it seems the cause, and I am researching how was the mechanism.

Comment: Finally I got the cause: From 2.4.0, `table_manager` module thought not must need when running in single mode(`target: all`). And if you want it works, just run a table_manager micro service(`target: table_manager`).

Comment: I found it by debug the code, and find Loki manage modules by a modules dependency mechanism, and `table_manager` module isn't dependents by any module especially by `all`

Comment: The dependencies assembled in `pkg/loki/loki.go #setupModuleManager`

Comment: In my situation, I set `target: all, table_manager` and it resolves