# Loki gives error table index_2797 does not exist when using Cassandra as store

Tags: cassandra, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I'm using Cassandra as the data and index store for Grafana Loki, following the guidelines in the [Grafana Documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/storage/#on-prem-deployment-cassandracassandra). However, I'm encountering an error stating that the table 'index_XXXX' does not exist. Is there a configuration step that I might have overlooked?"

Docker compose for loki

```yaml
loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.8.0
    ports:
      - 3100:3100
    volumes:
      - ./config/loki-config.yml:/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
    networks:
      - app
```

loki config file

```yaml
target: all

auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  
common:
  path_prefix: /loki
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-07-01
      store: cassandra
      object_store: cassandra
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 168h
      chunks:
        prefix: chunk_
        period: 168h
  
storage_config:
  cassandra:
    addresses: cassandra
    keyspace: loki1
    auth: false
    replication_factor: 1
    timeout: 100s
    connect_timeout: 100s
    max_retries: 3
  filesystem:
    directory: /loki/chunks

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 168h
  
limits_config:
  retention_period: 168h
  allow_deletes: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for with the help of the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433198/loki-internal-server-error-500-table-loki-index2711-does-not-exist?rq=2) .
I am posting the solution here as it may be helpful for someone who faced the same problem. It is same loki config file but we should include "table-manager" as a value of target key. So loki will create the tables.

```
target: all,table-manager
auth_enabled: false
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
common:
  path_prefix: /loki
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory  
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-07-01
      store: cassandra
      object_store: cassandra
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 168h
      chunks:
        prefix: chunk_
        period: 168h 
storage_config:
  cassandra:
    addresses: cassandra
    keyspace: loki1
    auth: false
    replication_factor: 1
    timeout: 100s
    connect_timeout: 100s
    max_retries: 3
  filesystem:
    directory: /loki/chunks
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 168h  
limits_config:
  retention_period: 168h
  allow_deletes: true
query_range:
  parallelise_shardable_queries: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You had to add `--target=all,table-manager` to command arguments and then Loki creates the tables.

Alternatively, you could add to `config.yaml`

```yaml
target: all,table-manager
```

References:

- https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/upgrading/#the-single-binary-no-longer-runs-a-table-manager
- https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/9127#issuecomment-1626391268